# How to translate JSON in ByteArray from ActionScript 3 to Java

Tags: java, json, flash, actionscript, decode

I have a problem in translating saved Object from ActionScript 3 to Java.
Saved object it is JSON object saved in ByteArray (from ActionScript side).
In Java I need this JSON as String. I tried different ways, but still unsuccessfully.
Maybe someone can advice and help me?

Comment: Consider adding some more details to your question such as what you've already tried and maybe some relevant code.

Comment: I can be more specific, but it may confuse you. I tryied to use java different Java JSON libraries, also tried to use recoded AMF3 deserialization methods from BlazeDS, tried to recognize with custom code, also used haxe conversion posibilities. For example problem in haxe: "You cannot access the flash package while targeting java (for flash.utils.ByteArray)". 
So I add custom flash2.utils.ByteArray to my Haxe project, but  building process cant find this flash2.utils.ByteArray. So the last problem there to define for haxe the correct path for flash2.utils.ByteArray.

Comment: @MarkAntonio in Java, JSON should come via one of usual sources: `InputStream`, `Reader`, `byte[]` or `String`, and from there decoded/parsed using a library like GSON or Jackson. So whatever your input source is just needs to spit out contents as one of those things -- especially since `ByteArray` really sounds like a simple wrapper around `byte[]` and can either expose or produce one of those.

Comment: @StaxMan Yes, sounds really simple, but maybe already exists ready instruments for emulating ActionScript "readObject"?

Comment: @MarkAntonio if you mean read JSON from external sources as Java POJOs, there are many libraries that do just that; GSON, Jackson, Genson, Boon (etc etc). For Jackson that'd be `ObjectMapper.readValue(source, PojoType.class)`

Comment: @StaxMan No, I need to readObject from ActionScript3.